# Smack xmpp automatically disconnected using smack 4.4.4

Tags: xmpp, smack

Earlier we have used smack 4.3.4 and Xmpp connection working fine . When we upgrade to smack 4.4.4 , we are facing Xmpp automatically disconnected while device is idle.

Comment: Does your PingFailedListener return an error?

Answer (score 0):

You can check server's Idle Connections Policy and increase the time out, or you can ping the server at some interval to keep the XMPP connection alive.